# rhnsd daemon on Ubuntu

Tags: daemon

I just bought a dell server (to learn stuff) and i was asking our sysadmin some security questions.

I just installed Ubuntu server and he gave me a long list of things to do for me to secure, check.

one of them is:

- Make sure you turn off the "rhnsd daemon"

so i tired it but I get:

```
root@w1a:~$ chkconfig rhnsd off
The program 'chkconfig' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install chkconfig
```

so i checked:

```
root@w1a:~$ rhnsd
rhnsd: command not found
```

So, am i missing something? or this tool or software is not installed by default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This daemon (`rhnsd`) is unique to Red Hat flavors - it's the "Red Hat Network Services Daemon". I'm pretty sure the `chkconfig` script is also Red Hat specific.